# Some help needed selenium python locating name

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the name and email from here. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28958615/. The problem is When you click on the link next to the name it "expands" the section below it...and takes you there. There is no way to know which name's respective link would have an email in it's description. So, I am stuck at getting either but not both. This is a very simple site..so, no issues with finding elements. Hope someone could help with the logic here.
I am doing this..though this is not correct, I know.

```
Aut_div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inline-authors')
nam_a = Aut_div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for name in nam_a:
    try:
        name.click()
        lis = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('li').text
        if '@' in lis:
          print(lis)
          print(name.text)
          break
    except:
      continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the following logic:

1. Find all elements using the class locator: authors-list-item
2. For each author item find all a tags (find_elements method)
   -first tag contains author name - get the name
   -second tag contains link to reference details - get attribute href
3. Using the value of href attribute find element by css locator [data-affiliation-id={id}] (you have to remove # from its value: #affiliation-1 -> affiliation-1
4. Extract the inner text of element found using locator from point 3. -> here you can find email -> extract it using RegEx (e.g. ([a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))

Comment: The author link is a different link altogether, we need the numbered link next to the author's name

Comment: Clicking on `href ` will open a new page with the same information. Also, would need to switch to that window. This is already a window I switch to.

Comment: Need, something like this. My guess. Get the `key` of the element which has email . Then go back up the page, refresh the page. then look for the author with that key, That , I can do, but the author name is the parent element of the `key` element...No way to move UP. So, Even if we find the author with that key, no way to move UP one element and get name.

Comment: When you find element with class 'authors-list-item' you have element that contains two links. Use this element to get a tag elements - get the author from the first link and the href attribute from the second. 
Don't click on this second link (with href), you don't have to click on anything actually - just get the element using href value as a part of locator and get inner text of located element - there you have an email.

Comment: Doesn't work  If you look at the properties of the `href` ..You can see the innerHTML attribute just has the link number..No text.

Comment: I solved it by the original method. Refresh the page. Find the authors. If the link number is in the affiliation text, get the name.

Comment: If it works for you - that's fine. Definitely, you haven't get my idea - I should express myself in a clearer manner. 
Yes, affiliation li has a number - but it also has a child sup element where details are stored. By getting innerText you also get inner text of child elements